# How can I sort by multiple fields in mongodb with Perl?

Tags: mongodb, perl, sorting, mongodb-query

How can I get multiple sort in MongoDB with Perl?

My current approach looks something like this:

```
my $sort = {"is_instock" => -1, "ua" => 1};
my $resultSet = $collection
   ->find({moderated => 1, markers => {'$all'=>$obj->{markers}}})
   ->sort($sort)
   ->limit(25);
@{$result} = $resultSet->all;
```

But, i got array  sorted by one field(ua). What i did wrong?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about markers. Here it is $obj->{markers} = [168,169]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and to the Perl tag! You can [edit] your question and add those details with the [edit] link on the bottom left of the question. Please feel free to also take the [tour] to get more familiar with the site. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem here is that a "hash" in Perl is ordered by "key" by default. In order to get the "order of insertion" you need to use [`Tie::IxHash`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash) as follows:

```
use Tie::IxHash;

my %sort;
tie ( %sort, 'Tie::IxHash' );

my $sort = \%sort;
$sort  =  { "is_instock" => -1, "ua" => 1 };
```

Then when you use this in your MongoDB query, the keys are considered in the order you inserted them, rather than their lexcial order.

It should have been orderd that way anyhow since the keys are in lexical order, but I suggest you did something wrong and you need to be aware of the insertion order anyway.

The otherwise reason is that "in_stock" does not exist, or is not the true path name to the field. You need to specifiy the full path to the field with ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) otherwise the path is invalid.

Comment: Thank you, it's work. But it's work only if i declare "hash" like this:              $sort->{is_instock} = -1; $sort->{ua} = 1;

Comment: @ArtemBardachov Works fine for me if declared exatly as shown. It's all about `Tie:IxHash` as mentioned since that is the only way a hash is re-defined to work in the insertion order as expected by BSON which is the eventual serialization of the request. Default Perl hashes do not respect that order as is already stated.

Comment: A hash in Perl isn't sorted at all by default.

Comment: This saved me a lot of pain, thank you @BlakesSeven