# Error when trying to use MongoDB's cursor sort in Perl

Tags: mongodb, perl

[This documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/Cursor.pm#sort) described how to sort the results once you've obtained a cursor.

However, When I try to compile with my own implementation:

```
#!/asp_share/linopt/perl-5.8.8/bin/perl

use CGI;
use Fcntl;
use MongoDB;
use JSON;
use Text::CSV;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $q = new CGI;
my $dbhost = $q->param('dbhost') || 'sb2mdb01';
print $q->header('application/json');

# Connect to db and retrieve stats for given db
my $client = MongoDB::Connection->new("host" => $dbhost);
my $tracking_db = $client->get_database("db_size_tracking");
my $db_name = "st_" . ($q->param('db') || "db_size_tracking" );
my $collection = $tracking_db->get_collection($db_name);
my $every = $q->param('every') || 1;  # sample per $every line
my $date = $q->param('date') || `date +%Y%m%d`; # date to start from
chomp($date);
my $year = substr($date,0,4);
my $month = "".substr($date,4,2);
my $day = "".substr($date,6,2);
my $cursor = $collection->find({recorded_at => {'$gte' => DateTime->new( year => $year, month => $month, day => $day)}});
$cursor->sort([recorded_at => 1]);
# Generate and return JSON
my @sizeTimes;
my $count = 0;
while (my $doc = $cursor->next) {
    next if ($count++ % $every != 0);
    my $recorded_at = $doc->{'recorded_at'}->iso8601;
    my $datasize = $doc->{'datasize'};
    my %row;
    $row{'recorded_at'} = $recorded_at;
    $row{'datasize'} = $datasize;
    push @sizeTimes, \%row;
}

print encode_json {sizeTimes => \@sizeTimes};
```

I get

```
not a hash reference at /linopt/perl-5.8.8/lib/site_perl/5.8.8/i686-linux/MongoDB/Cursor.pm line 182
        MongoDB::Cursor::sort('MongoDB::Cursor=HASH(0x8e87160)', 'ARRAY(0x8e86614)')
```

I'm fairly new to perl, so I'm not really sure how to interpret this error message, any help would be really appreciated!

The documents returned are of the form

```
{recorded_at: recorded_at, datasize: datasize}
```

Perl: v5.8.8
MongoDB: 3.0.7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Сухой27 I'm not really sure what other information I'd need to add to this, versions of perl/Mongodb?

Comment: How about showing a document you expect to return in result and the other lines of code including the collection selection and `->find()`. Did you also read the documentation about the other valid structures to use and did you try them? If so then show that as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn updated with the entire script. The .find definitely works, but I'm graphing this data later using the google api and would like to sort it at query time.

Comment: Having a little knowledge of Perl data structures will help you. Generally `{ recorded_at => 1 }` should be what you want here because it's just a single field. For "multiple" fields in a sort see [How can I sort by multiple fields in mongodb with Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967038/how-can-i-sort-by-multiple-fields-in-mongodb-with-perl) which might give a bit more insight into what the documentation alludes to.

Comment: @NeilLunn that worked great thank you! If you want to post that as an answer for the rep I'll mark it as accepted. Would it be correct to say that the Docs are wrong (or maybe just outdated)? As the example you linked also uses curly brackets rather than square.

Comment: What version of the driver are you using?  That shouldn't be happening on recent versions of the driver.

Comment: @xdg likely an older one, the only reason I'm working in perl in the first place is because of a legacy codebase

Comment: OK.  Keep in mind that if it's older that v1.0, the current docs you linked to won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$cursor->sort({recorded_at => 1});
```

Can also be used to sort by [multiple fields.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967038/how-can-i-sort-by-multiple-fields-in-mongodb-with-perl)

The documentation is for the newer MongoDB driver for perl, which I bet if you're looking this up too, you're stuck with.